# How may virtual tables are created in multiple inheritance. What about the sizes?

Tags: c++

```
class A1
{
public:
    A1()
    {
        cout << "Inside Constructor A1." << endl;

    }
    virtual void fA1()
    {
        cout << "fA1() is called" << endl;
    }
};

class B1
{
public:
    B1()
    {
        cout << "Inside Constructor B1." << endl;
    }
    virtual void fB1()
    {
        cout << "fB2() is called" << endl;
    }

};

class C1: public B1, public A1
{
public:
    C1()
    {
        cout << "Inside Constructor C1" << endl;
    }
    virtual void fc1()
    {
        cout << "fc1() is called " << endl;
    }
};

cout << "Size of A1 class : " << sizeof(A1) << endl; //Gives 4

cout << "size of B1 Class : " << sizeof(B1) << endl;//4

cout << "size of C1 class : " << sizeof(C1) << endl;//8
```

why it happens?
if vptr of class A and B are inherited into B(size of class C is 8)
then, what about vptr of class c ?i.e, size of c should be 16.
How the vtable is structured for class c ?
is there any possible to see vtable in visual studio.

Comment: vtables are not defined by the standard. It is likely but not certain that most implementations follow Lippman, *Inside The C++ Object Model,* Addison Wesley.

Comment: The sizes of the types have very little to do with vtables. Vtables are generated *per class*, not per object, and the size of a type is a property of *objects* of that type. What you're seeing is much more closely related to base layout optimizations, or the lack thereof.

Comment: @Kerrek SB please, explain structure of vtable of calss C1

Comment: Class `C` will contain two virtual tables. For more information read http://shaharmike.com/cpp/vtable-part2/